# Hyper-V causes the error "sorry, this application cannot run under a virtual machine"

Tags: windows, virtualization, virtual-machine, hyper-v

After installing Hyper-V in the windows, I get the following error for running a game in my windows. Of course I am not running it in the virtual machine. I want to run the game in the PC itself that I installed the Hyper-V.

> sorry, this application cannot run under a virtual machine

Even I tried to stop the Hyper-V service inside the Hyper-V management but that doesn't work for me and I get the same error. Please help me find a solution to this.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you contact game vendor support, this is a clearly bug in this game, nothing to do with Hyper-v itself

Comment: I want a rapid solution, I can't wait for them to build a update or I can't uninstall the Hyper-V because I do my network projects tests with that. I thing there should be a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a good solution. making an entry in the boot loader, so that the hypervisor will not start by choosing that option while restarting the system. here is the steps to this:

1.At the command prompt, type the following:

```
bcdedit /copy {default} /d "No Hypervisor"
```

2.The above command should say: `The entry was successfully copied to {guid}`.
Copy that guid to the clipboard including the curly braces.

3.Now, type the following command:

```
bcdedit /set {guid} hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

In the above command, replace {guid} with what you copied in step 2.
I found the solution here : [Hyper-V and VMware Workstation on the same computer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/servervirtualization/thread/e9c72bc8-c48d-453b-9f33-143114adecee).
It works for me and I hope it will works for people having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the game copy-protection trying to stop you from running the game in a sandbox such as a virtual machine, where you'd be able to automate (bot) the game or hack the game by poking memory from outside of the machine.

The only way to resolve this issue is for you to either

A) Uninstall VirtualPC/Hyper-V *completely*

B) Ask the game company to change their policy, explaining precisely why you need Hyper-V and would like to play their game on the same machine, and wait for them to push out an update.

Comment: I need Hyper-V to test my network projects. but when I stop the Hyper-V service completely the game developer company could make sure about the hack issue, so their limitation is not reasonable. And are you sure there is no other way to stop the game bringing up this message.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the game copy-protection trying to be clever and detecting Hyper-V and assuming the reason you have it is to pirate the game (yes, I know this is wrong, but that's what *it* thinks). Your best bet is to formally complain to the company that sold you the game and tell them that this is an unreasonable restriction on your ability to use their software, and a restriction that you were not made aware of before you purchased the game and ask them to release a patch that makes it possible for you to play your game on a machine that is also a Hyper-V host with Hyper-V off.